# Why doesn't Oracle expdp create the dump file?

Tags: oracle, expdp

I'm trying to export a schema from an Oracle 10.2.0.5.0 database. For some reason, when I launch the expdp command, it finishes almost immediately and it only creates the log file, no dump file at all. It must be some silly mistake but I can't figure it out.

This is the command I'm executing on the server (logged in SSH as the Oracle user):

```
expdp my_user/my_pass@db schemas=my_user directory=my_dir dumpfile=exp.dmp logfile=exp.log
```

With SYS I get the same result:

```
expdp \"sys/sys_pass@db as sysdba\" schemas=my_user ...
```

There is only one database in the server, so I've also tried without the `@db` part. Same result.

I've checked that `my_dir` is properly defined and points to an existing filesystem location on the server, with available space (~3.4 GB free) and where the Oracle user can read and write. I've also granted read and write privileges to `my_user` on `my_dir`. And I've quadruple-checked that `my_user` is the correct schema with the tables I want to export.

This is the only output I get, both on the console (except the `;;;`) and the logfile:

```
;;; 
Export: Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit Production on Monday, 08 April, 2019 13:27:31

Copyright (c) 2003, 2007, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
;;; 
Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

And then nothing. No dump file, no errors, no nothing. It just ends.

I've found [this page](https://databaseinternalmechanism.com/2016/09/13/how-to-monitor-datapump-jobs/) with a few useful (?) queries. `v$datapump_job` and `dba_resumable` are empty. There are a few exports in `dba_datapump_jobs`, all of them with status `NOT RUNNING`; I don't know for sure because there isn't any "date" field, but I think they are old jobs, they don't change when I launch the `expdp` command.

What else can I check?

**Edit**: if I run `echo $?` immediately after the `expdp` command, it outputs `1`, which according to [this page (for Oracle 12c, not 10.2...)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-34D0DEE7-3530-42DC-BE01-C2588CC73CE5.htm#SUTIL3834), means "exit with fatal errors". Yet, not important enough to write them in the logfile?

Comment: Just want to make sure that you know that the datapump directory is on the RDBMS server and not local?

Comment: Thanks Phil. Yes, I knew, that's where I'm checking the output log file.

Comment: Does my_user have the EXP_FULL_DATABASE role? If not, try the export as that user without any SCHEMAS parameter.

Comment: I just tried without the schemas parameter... and it failed again, but at least now it's showing an error: `ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP`. It seems like the Oracle partition doesn't have any available space. Hopefully that was causing all the issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with the TEMP tablespace, which was stored in a disk partition with no more available space.

Following [CaM's suggestion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/234178/why-doesnt-oracle-expdp-create-the-dump-file#comment462194_234178) (thanks!), I checked that my_user doesn't have the `EXP_FULL_DATABASE` role, so I launched again the `expdp` command but without the `schemas` parameter. For some reason, doing it this way Oracle finally took pity of me, gave up its shenanigans and decided to show the error:

```
ORA-39125: Worker unexpected fatal error in KUPW$WORKER.DISPATCH_WORK_ITEMS while calling
           DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY []
ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP
```

After ["moving" the temp datafile](https://dbaclass.com/article/how-to-drop-and-recreate-temp-tablespace-in-oracle/) to another partition and having a nice fight with [Unix to release the disk space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34140/tell-fs-to-free-space-from-deleted-files-now/64737#64737), the expdp finally works again.